# FileReader, File and TextDecoder in Jest Test not defined

Tags: javascript, typescript, unit-testing, jestjs

before I only do tests with Jasmine now I try Jest but facing the problem that things like `FileReader, File and TextDecoder` are not defined in my tests.
How can I use this classes with their real function to test my class that uses them?

Comment: Importing them into your tests? Or use [setupFiles](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/configuration#setupfiles-array) to import all the modules required globally for all test suites.

Answer (score 4):

At least for `TextDecoder` I've found a way around with the help of @josephting's comment. It's really hacky since it requires you to install a dev dependency that is also deprecated and no longer maintained called `text-encoding`.

First you need to define `setupFiles` in your `jest.config.js`:

```
[...]
setupFiles: ['./tests/setupEnv.js'],
[...]
```

And you also need to require the mentioned package globally in your `setupEnv.js`:

```js
TextDecoder = require('text-encoding').TextDecoder;
```

Comment: The following worked for me, from Node.js's included `util` package:
`const { TextDecoder } = require('util');
global.TextDecoder = TextDecoder;`

Comment: Thanks @zzzachzzz  - please consider posting this as an answer - it worked for me :)

Comment: @zzzachzzz solutions does work, the package `text-encoding` does not contain Class TextDecoder in current version

Answer (score 1):

I found a work around this issue, I added the TextEncoder and TextDecoder as a global variable in jest.

I added this to my `jest.config`

```
const { TextDecoder, TextEncoder } = require('util')

module.exports = {
  globals: {
    TextDecoder: TextDecoder,
    TextEncoder: TextEncoder,
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're using Jest then the best solution is from Arthur Medeiros: Just allow jest to have access to the appropriate global variables it needs. Note that you probably don't need to import `util` since `TextDecoder` and `TextEncoder` should be on the global scope in your jest config file; you only need `globals: { TextDecoder, TextEncoder },` in your config file's export.

*But* there could be times where you're don't want to include these globals for *all* tests in your suite (and don't want to have another config file), or are using something other than jest. In those cases you can just add this to your test file:

```js
import { TextDecoder, TextEncoder } from 'node:util'; // (ESM style imports)

global.TextDecoder = TextDecoder;
global.TextEncoder = TextEncoder;

// Do whatever you wanted to do... (for me, it was using node-fetch)
```